# How do I disable logging from javers?

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, javers

Currently working in a large spring-boot application, it would be preferred to disable logging if possible to reduce noise.

sample of the logs

```
NFO org.javers.core.JaversBuilder mappingStyle: FIELD
NFO org.javers.core.JaversBuilder loading GroovyAddOns ...
NFO org.javers.core.JaversBuilder using fake InMemoryRepository, register actual Repository implementation via JaversBuilder.registerJaversRepository()
NFO org.javers.core.JaversBuilder JaVers instance started in 116 ms
```

How do I disable logging from javers?

Comment: Build only one Javers instance as Javers is suppose to be thread safe : https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/423

Answer (score 2):

You can set log level for Javers in `logback.xml` like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.javers.SQL" level="DEBUG"/>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration you should only see `DEBUG` log messages displayed in pattern above.

If you want to completly disable logging you can use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.javers.SQL" level="OFF"/>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The instruction: `level="OFF"` tells Logback to disable all log output for a given logger, in your case that is javers logger.

Comment: hello @Nemanja Is there any to way to achieve this using the application.properties files instead of a logback.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, you can set the logging level in the application.properties file.

For example (if you only want WARN or above):

```
logging.level.org.javers=WARN
```